# How to check in batch script if "mysqldump" and "mysql" commands succeeded or not?

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file

I'm running `mysqldump` and `mysql` commands from a batch script on Windows to make a backup of a database and restore it.

How could I check in the batch script whether these commands executed correctly or end up with error ? In case of error, I would like to know what the error is.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is, you could redirect the error to a file

```
mysqldump [options] > dumpfile 2> error.log
```

You can look for various error possibilities in the log file and take appropriate actions

Comment: is it also possible to delete the error.log file is there were errors? else you'll get files with 0kb. Of course you can check is those files exists but I was wondering through..